# Magento 2.4.3 - Module and Theme Installation not working

Tags: module, theme, magento2.4, installation, composer

I have installed Magento 2.4.3 via composer and trying to install custom frontend/admin theme and custom modules. These modules are already working in version 2.3 that have been copied and added at below path

Frontend Theme - `C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/app/design/frontend/NameSpace/FrontTheme`

Backend Theme - `C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/app/design/adminhtml/NameSpace/AdminTheme`

Custom Module - `C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/app/code/NameSpace/MyModule`

Executed commands as below

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

However, it is showing Nothing to import message. Also the module entry could not be seen in the table `setup_module` and the frontend looks like below. Moreover the admin panel in inaccessible.

[image]

[image]

Has the module installation method changed from version 2.4.3 or do I need to update my composer file in order to install local modules (not marketplace/third party modules)?

P.S. - I had first installed the backend theme and did not see anything imported so I installed frontend theme but no luck. To verify if modules are correctly installed, I later installed custom module but that as well did not show entry in `setup_module` table

Upon console review - it says page not found for the url - `http://localhost/myproject/pub/static/version1627395423/frontend/_view/en_US/mage/calendar.css`

Comment: Have a look in your browser console and see what the errors are.

Comment: You should also do one thing at a time so you can pinpoint what causes the error. Like just install the frontend theme first, and see if that works. Then backend theme, see if that works. Then add your modules, check they work. We're not going to have a clue where the issue lies from what you've posted above.

Comment: @zigojacko - Question updated.

Comment: Try [this answer already posted](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/341881/798)... And then let us know if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento cache:flush 
chmod -R 777 generated var pub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below commands

Remove the generated files in the pu/static folder

```
 sudo   rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/* generated/*
```

Generate the new files under pub/static

```php
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

If the above doesn't work please check the **theme** table and change the active theme type as **0** and execute the above command once again.